# Зачем в Laravel 8 роутинг сделали неудобнее?

Tags: laravel

Господа, я только учу лару и в основном учил ее на уроках в сети для 5-7 версии. И привык что роутер пишется например так

```
Route::get('/', 'MainController@main')->name('main');
```

Объясните мне начинающему зачем в 8 версии все усложнили и теперь это выглядит так

```
Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\MainController::class, 'main'])->name('main');
```

Зачем усложнили запись, в чем тут новизна и преимущество?

P.S. с помощью правки файла RouteServiceProvider.php вернул стиль написания как в 7-й версии, но может я что-то не понимаю и не вижу нового удобства?

Comment: [Routing upgrade](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade#routing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]1. вы можете улучшить читаемость используя use

```php
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\MainController;

Route::get('/', [MainController::class, 'main'])->name('main');
```

2. Можно быстро перемещаться в данный контроллер используя IDE и кликая по MainController::class с зажатой клавишей Ctrl.
   Это гораздо удобнее + меньше вероятность допустить опечатку в пути или названии класса, так как IDE подсвечивает классы, но не значения в строках.